# Swift - created parse nested xml issue

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse XML and want to display data in table view. If there are 4 ListSections tags in XML then, table view will have 4 sections and each section will display row according to data. Each ListSection tag is having number of Team tags. I want to display those Teams in row according to sections.

This is my XML structure.

```
 <List>
   <ListSection sectionName="section 1">
      <Team id="10" name="Team1">
          <OppositeTeam oppName="TeamX" day="Monday"/>
      </Team>
      <Team id="20" name="Team2">
          <OppositeTeam oppName="TeamY" day="Tuesday"/>
      </Team>
   </ListSection> 
   <ListSection sectionName="section 2">
      <Team id="100" name="Team100">
          <OppositeTeam oppName="TeamA" day="Monday"/>
      </Team>
      <Team id="200" name="Team200">
          <OppositeTeam oppName="TeamB" day="Monday"/>
      </Team>
   </ListSection> 
 </List>
```

I am trying to create Model class for this xml. 
I have created 2 class so far.

```
class ListSection {
  var sectionName: String = String()
  var team : [Team] = []
}

class Team {
  var teamId:String = String()
  var teamName:String = String()
}
```

I am not sure about this data model which I have created. Can anyone please suggest me if I am going in right or wrong direction?

Thanks in advance.

Updated: 
This is my Swift parsing code. I am not able to save data in proper object.

```
var listSection: [ListSection] = []
var teamArray : [Team] = []
var teamData = NSMutableArray()

var sectionName = String()
var teamName = String()

var listSectionObj = ListSection()

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    if elementName == "ListSection" {
        listSectionObj = ListSection()
        listSectionObj.sectionName = ""
        listSectionObj.team = [] 
        if let sectionName = attributeDict["sectionName"] as String? {
            self. sectionName = sectionName
        }
    }else if elementName == "Team" {
         if let teamName = attributeDict["TeamName"] as String? {
            self.teamName = teamName
        }
    }
}


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "ListSection" {

        listSectionObj.sectionName = sectionName
        listSection.append(listSectionObj)
    }else if elementName == "Team" {
        teamObj = Team()
        teamObj.teamName = teamName
        teamArray.append(teamObj)
        print("teamArray = \(teamArray)") 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by you are not able to save data in object, but if you want to store custom objects, I strongly suggest to look into this: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Also, your data structure seems good according to the XML structure.